# LinkedIn REST API does not return end-date with python

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I'm working on Linkedin REST API. I cannot get postions' end-date.

```
connectionsdic = application.get_connections(selectors=['id', 
            'positions','specialties','first-name','last-name',
            'headline','public-profile-url','site-standard-profile-request'],
             params=`{'start':130, 'count':100})
```

I can get anything else.

**Edit:** I changed my code to be most straight, but still same result...

Answer (score 0):

Try just specifying `positions` without the :['end-date'] part, in the same you specify `educations`.

Also note that end date will not be returned if the position is current.

Comment: I used positions only before, but did not worked. I also know that it will not return end-date for current position, but I can't get end-date for previous positions.

Comment: How can I tell to LinkedIn API that send end-date for previous positions ?